# Debug EventReceiver on multi Server Farm environment using Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I am having a multi server environment having 2 WFEs & one SQL Server DB box.I have installed office developer tools for VS 2012 .But I am unable to debug my item added event receiver like my single server farm development environment. Do I need to have extra settings or configuration on this multi server farm environment in order to have a smooth debugging.